# HTML Imports with the Async flag - strange behaviour in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, polymer

I am trying to optimise the loading of Polymer Elements in my Polymer based web app.  In particular I am concentrating my effort around the initial start up screens.  Users will have to log on if they don't have a valid jwt token held in a cookie.

`index.html` loads an application element `<pas-app>` which in turn loads an session manager (`<pas-eession>`).  Since the normal startup will be when the user is already logged on the element that handles input of user name and password (`<pas-logon>`) is hidden behind a `<template is="dom-if">` element inside of `<pas-session>`and I have added the `async` flag to its html import line in that element as well - thus :

`<link rel="import" href="pas-logon.html" async>`

However, in chrome (I don't experience this in firefox, where  html imports are polyfilled) this async seems to flow over embedded `<script>` element inside the custom element.  In particular I get a type error because the script to cause it to be regestered as a custom element thinks `Polymer` is not a function.

I suspect I am using the wrong kind of async flag - is there a way to specify that the html import should not block the current element, but should block the scripts inside itself when loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same problem today and found this question when searching for a solution. When using importHref async I get errors like `[paper-radio-button::_flattenBehaviorsList]: behavior is null, check for missing or 404 import` and dependencies are not loaded in the right order. When I change to async = false the error messages are gone.

It seems that this is a known bug of Polymer or probably Chrome https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2522